# Cant loop through users to send them individual message FB.ui()

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am looking for a way to send messages to multiple people without creating group chats and I have been working on this for two days now. I am trying to use a little hack where it loops through and ID list and basically takes values in an array and loops through them so one by one it sends a message. Basically, one ID sends message, then it loops back second ID sends message and so on until all parties have received a message. Here is my code so far

```
tl1.addEventListener("click", function() { //Send Message
    try
    {
        var users = ['100008601850848', '100002242788752'];
        for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++)
        {
            FB.ui({
                app_id: '1226220854077249',
                method: 'SEND',
                link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/apps/1226220854077249/roles/test-users/',
                to: users[i]
            });
        }
    }
    catch(error)
    {
        console.log(error);
    }
}, false);
```

Am I approaching this right? It does not send a message to all of them it only puts the first user in the field. All I am trying to do is make a loop that sends messages to one user then the next and so on. Basically sending it to multiple ID's but without creating groups as the FB.UI() does

Comment: what is your question? does it work?

Comment: No it does not work.

Comment: That's kinda why I posted it here. My question is basically I want to send to multiple people but I don't want to make group chats

Comment: so what does "it does not work" mean? what do you expect? multiple popup windows?

Comment: Well basically, it shows the window, (btw I do not want to spam the users with windows - I just want to send a message to multiple people without it putting them into a group chat), but only sends it to one person. I want it to loop through all people and send a message to them

Comment: there is only one way to use the send dialog, and if it creates a group chat then that´s what you have to live with, i would say. right now you are trying to open several popups at once, which is a pretty ugly workaround - if it even works.

Comment: My company is postponing this until further notice. They have me working on my next project. I thank you for your help @luschn - Just post your answer as an.... answer lol and Ill accept it.

Comment: alright, done. thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one way to use the send dialog, and if it creates a group chat then that´s what you have to live with. Right now you are trying to open several popups at once, which is a pretty ugly workaround - if it even works.